# React Bootstrap Expand All/Collapse All <Panel.Body> component created in map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a `react-bootstrap` app out of nested PanelGroup components. I everything is working correctly, but now I have been asked to add an expand all / collapse all link. Since I am generating the panels through a map loop, I am not totally sure if this is possible or not. Here is what I have so far:

```
{data.map((item, i)=>{
                return (
                    <PanelGroup key={i + 1} accordion id={(i + 1).toString() + 'accordion'}>
                        <Panel key={i + 1} eventKey={(i + 1).toString() }>
                            <Panel.Heading>
                                <Panel.Title toggle>
                                    {this.getHeaderNode(i, data)}
                                </Panel.Title>
                            </Panel.Heading>
                            <Panel.Body collapsible>
                                { this.getChildrenNode(i, data) }
                            </Panel.Body>
                        </Panel>
                    </PanelGroup>
                );
            })}
```

I have tried implementing some different attributes as described in the [docs here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/)

For instance, I have added an attribute to `Panel.Body` that will listen to the state:

```
expanded={this.state.expanded}
```

Then, my thinking was to add a button as another component that will fire a function on click, such as:

```
_toggleExpand: function() {
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
  }
```

But, how do I get the Panels to determine whether the user clicked the collapse/expand all button, or if the user clicked on the `Panel.Title` to expand/collapse the single panel?

Comment: I would let a parent manage the open/closed state and let the children (collapsible items) use the state. e.g. `expanded={this.state.items[index].expanded}` and `toggle: (index) => // this.setState by index`

Comment: Just to clarify. I would not use `PanelGroup` because I can't see from the docs how to support the feature you want. I would simply use multiple Panel component inside my custom parent component and let that control the expanded state for all the panels.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kunukn guessed, the Panel.Group does not support the collapse all expand all functionality that I was looking for. So, I simply added the native bootstrap classes to the appropriate html divs:

```
<div key={(n + i).toString() + 'nested'} className={'card'}>
                        <div className={'card-header'} >
                            <h3>
                                <a className={ ('collapsed ' + nestedClass).toString() }
                                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target={'#' + n + 'panel' + random}>
                                    {this.getHeaderNode(n, childUnits)}
                                    </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id={n + 'panel' + random} className={ 'collapse' }>
                            <div className={'panelBody'}>
                                { this.getChildrenNodes(n, childUnits, false) }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Then, applied the jQuery Bootstrap collapse method to an event listener:

```
$('#accordion .collapse.in').collapse('hide');
```

Since I don't need to change the state of this component after the initial page load, this works for my purposes.